# How to initialize Django ModelForms on an entire queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am building an ad manager software, and I want to use django's ModelForm system to load an entire queryset of Ad objects so that users can alter fields in an already running/existing ad.

I want to do this preferably in an alternative way to the [modelformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) method.

For example, if a user has a single Ad model you could simply call that instance and load the instance into a modelForm instance called AdForm so that they can edit the ad's properties:

```
ad_instance = Ad.objects.get(pk=1)
ad_form = AdForm(instance=ad_instance)
```

So what about if the user has 20 active ads running? How can a queryset of 20 ad instances be loaded into their respective AdForms?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use modelformset_factory. That's exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [Change the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)

```
AdFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ad, fields=('name', 'title'))
formset = AdFormSet(queryset=request.user.ad_set.all())
```